# Rails multiple radio buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table named `items` and three boolean columns `fixed_amount, no_price, per_hour`.

How can I add `radio buttons` of the above three columns to a form in order to submit as true if one is selected and false to rest of the columns that are not selected? I want the radio button to be able to toggle from one to another and not to select all three of them.

Currently I'm trying something like the following but without any luck:

```
<%= form.radio_button :no_price, '1', checked: true %>
<%= form.radio_button :fixed_amount, '1' %>
<%= form.radio_button :per_hour, '1' %>
```

Comment: I'd go with enum instead of separate columns, this was it's way easier and logically more correct: e.g `enum pricing_option: { no_price: 0, fixed_amount: 1, per_hour: 2 }` then in views: `<%= collection_radio_buttons(:foo, :pricing_option, Foo.pricing_options, :first, :first)%>`

Comment: check control radio button list https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/collection_radio_buttons

Comment: Thanks @Said Kaldybaev. this just worked fine!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with enum instead of separate columns, this was it's way easier and logically more correct: e.g

`enum pricing_option: { no_price: 0, fixed_amount: 1, per_hour: 2 }`

In views:

`<%= collection_radio_buttons(:foo, :pricing_option, Foo.pricing_options, :first, :first)%>`

Answer (score 1):

To have the radio buttons untoggle each other, they need to have the same name. Something like

```
<%= radio_button_tag :price_option, 'no_price', checked: model.no_price? %>
<%= radio_button_tag :price_option, 'fixed_amount', checked: model.fixed_amount? %>
...
```

Then you will receive in `params[:price_option]` the selected option, and set up your model accordingly.