# how to rewrite HTML code in a rails form helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, helper

I want to add a rating of 5 stars to the Comments model.
i have a form:

```
 <%= form_with(model: [ @product, @product.comments.build ], local: true) do |form| %>
  <p>
    <%= form.label t('activerecord.attributes.comment.commenter') %><br>
    <%= form.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.label t('activerecord.attributes.comment.body') %><br>
    <%= form.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= form.submit t('products.form.submit') %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

model:

```
# Table name: comments
#
#  id         :bigint           not null, primary key
#  body       :text
#  commenter  :string
#  rating     :float
#  created_at :datetime         not null
#  updated_at :datetime         not null
#  product_id :bigint           not null
```

I want to add a field :rating to this form .

HTML:

```
<div id="reviewStars-input">
  <input id="star-4" type="radio" value="5" name="reviewStars"/>
  <label title="gorgeous" for="star-4"></label>

  <input id="star-3" type="radio" value="4" name="reviewStars"/>
  <label title="good" for="star-3"></label>

  <input id="star-2" type="radio" value="3" name="reviewStars"/>
  <label title="regular" for="star-2"></label>

  <input id="star-1" type="radio" value="2" name="reviewStars"/>
  <label title="poor" for="star-1"></label>

  <input id="star-0" type="radio" value="1" name="reviewStars"/>
  <label title="bad" for="star-0"></label>
</div>
```

How to use helper rails so that in the model field:rating were entries numbered 1 to 5

Comment: Note that `form.label t('activerecord.attributes.comment.body')` can also be achieved by using [`comment.human_attribute_name(:body)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Translation.html#method-i-human_attribute_name). Assuming you've saved `@product.comments.build` to the `comment` variable first.

Comment: thanks but this does not relate to the topic of my question

Comment: you should use ruby radio list check this use of radio buttons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52662473/rails-multiple-radio-buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like the following:

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  STARS = [
    [5, 'gorgeous'],
    [4, 'good'],
    [3, 'regular'],
    ...
  ]
```

and

```
<div id="reviewStars-input">
  <%= collection_radio_buttons(:comment, :rating, Comment::STARS, :first, :second) do |b| %>
    <%= b.radio_button %>
    <%= b.label( title: b.text ) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

will get you close depending on exactly what labels and classes you need.

Comment: Have you tried this? Does it actually work with a hash?

Comment: Thanks @max, getting javascript and ruby mixed up.  Fixed my answer.